# Get each row of an arma::mat matrix as arma::vec in for loop

Tags: c++, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am using RcppArmadillo to create a function using stochastic simulation. I have trouble pulling out each row of a arma::mat as an arma::vec.

Below is a simplified example of my problem. I have used R nomenclature to illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

I believe there should be a fairly simple way of achieving this in C++, but I'm afraid I haven't figured it out yet. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>   
using namespace Rcpp;

    
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List function(List params) {
  arma::mat c= params["c"];
  arma::mat I= params["I"];
  
  
  for (int istep = 0; istep < (I.n_elem); istep++) {
    arma::vec loopedrows = I[istep,] //Here I have used the R indexing method, but this does not work in C++

    double product= accu(c*loopedrows)

    arma:vec newvec = stochastic_simulation(product) 

    I[istep+1,] =  newvec // store the output of the in matrix I, again the nomenclature is in R.
  }  

  
  return wrap(I);
};
```

Comment: Have you found the (rather excellent) [Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) yet?  Different ways of row and column access, indexing, slicing, ... are all explained there.

Comment: Hi Dirk thank you for your answer. Your online lecture on Rcpp has helped me massively in getting started with the package. 

Yes I have scoured the documentation, but could not manage to make it work yet. Would you have any functions in specific to recommend for this task?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple (and very pedestrian, going step by step in the loop) answer for you.

#### Code

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat rowwiseAdd(arma::mat A, arma::mat B) {
    if (A.n_rows != B.n_rows || A.n_cols != B.n_cols)
        Rcpp::stop("Matrices must conform.");

    arma::mat C(A.n_rows, A.n_cols);

    for (size_t i=0; i < A.n_rows; i++) {
        arma::rowvec a = A.row(i);
        arma::rowvec b = B.row(i);
        arma::rowvec c = a + b;
        C.row(i) = c;
    }
    return C;
}

/*** R
A <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
B <- matrix(9:1, 3, 3)
rowwiseAdd(A, B)
*/
```

#### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/70251105/answer.cpp")

> A <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)

> B <- matrix(9:1, 3, 3)

> rowwiseAdd(A, B)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   10   10
[2,]   10   10   10
[3,]   10   10   10
>
```